# When ever a question mark is imputed by a user it will display a string

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

Okay so basically iv been working on my school assignment which happens to be creating a very simple ChatterBot with java using Eclipse. So far iv gotten it to ask a series of questions if the user input contained a certain word, but i also need make it so when ever a "?" is entered (no matter at what point, it will probs make sense when you look at the code) it will display the string " i will be asking the questions", so far iv only got it to work only for the first time a user makes an input, then it goes to the next question and if you type a "?" nothing happens and the program ends.

okay so i see someone asked what the assignment is about to get a better idea on how to go about it, im really bad a explaining things but ill give it a try. For my assignment i need to create a 'Chatter Bot' and iv decided to go with a bot that asks you a few questions then gives you a fun fact (because i need to add at least 10 variables) so far iv got it to ask a question and take in  the user input and if the sentence they just typed contains a key word it will take that key word and run the next set of question while taking in user input and looking for the next key word for example it will first ask you to pick a subject like for example science, then it will ask you to pick a section of that subject like Biology, then it will state a fact and ask if you already knew that and you type yes or no, and according to that it will print out a string (key words they can chose from are typed in brackets)
Im sure there was a better way to explain all that but im really bad at them :/ sorry.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ChatterBot {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "";
    String maths = "";
    String science = "";
    String chemFact = "";
    String bioFact = "";
    String zooFact = "";
    String algFact = "";
    String yes = "";
    String no = "";
    input = JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog("Pick one of the subjects listed to learn a fun fact (english, science, maths) ");

    if (input.contains("science")) {
        science = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "What kind of science fact woukd you like to know about? (chem, Biology, Zoology)");
    }

    else if (input.contains("maths")) {
        maths = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "What kind of maths fact would you like to know about? (algebra, fractions, division) ");
    }
    if (maths.contains("algebra")) {
        algFact = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "\"Did you know a mathematician who specializes in algebra is called an algebraist? (yes or no)\"");
    }
    if (algFact.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Well good for you");
    } else if (algFact.contains("no")) {
        System.out.println("You learn something new everyday :)");
    }

    if (science.contains("chem")) {
        chemFact = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Did you know If you pour a handful of salt into a full glass of water the water level will actually go down rather than overflowing the glass? (yes or no)");
    }

    if (chemFact.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Well good for you");
    } else if (chemFact.contains("no")) {
        System.out.println("You learn something new everyday :)");
    }

    else if (science.contains("biology")) {
        bioFact = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Did you know The brain itself cannot feel pain? (yes or no)");
    }

    if (bioFact.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Well good for you");
    } else if (bioFact.contains("no")) {
        System.out.println("You learn something new everyday :)");
    }

    else if (science.contains("zoology")) {
        zooFact = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Did you know butterflies have taste receptors on their feet? (yes or no)");
    }

    if (zooFact.contains("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Well good for you");
    } else if (zooFact.contains("no")) {
        System.out.println("You learn something new everyday :)");
    }
    if (input.contains("?")) {
        System.out.println("I will be asking the questions");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Do you know what a loop is? Because you need one. You'd probably need to explain the desired behaviour in a bit more detail for us to be able to help you (but, if you can manage that, it shouldn't be a big step to just writing the code that does what you want).

Comment: hey i added more information, im bad with explaining stuff so i dont know how useful they will be :/

Also one thing i forgot to mention was it supposed to be really basic so the teacher didnt want us to use a loop, because thats part 2 of the project

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below in your code
     input = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Pick one of the subjects listed to learn a fun fact (english, science, maths) ");

```
        if (input.contains("science")) {
            science = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "What kind of science fact woukd you like to know about? (chem, Biology, Zoology)");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(science);
        }

        else if (input.contains("maths")) {
            maths = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "What kind of maths fact would you like to know about? (algebra, fractions, division) ");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(maths);
        }
        if (maths.contains("algebra")) {
            algFact = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "\"Did you know a mathematician who specializes in algebra is called an algebraist? (yes or no)\"");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(algFact);
        }
        if (algFact.contains("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Well good for you");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(algFact);
        } else if (algFact.contains("no")) {
            System.out.println("You learn something new everyday :)");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(algFact);
        }

        if (science.contains("chem")) {
            chemFact = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Did you know If you pour a handful of salt into a full glass of water the water level will actually go down rather than overflowing the glass? (yes or no)");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(chemFact);
        }

        if (chemFact.contains("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Well good for you");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(chemFact);
        } else if (chemFact.contains("no")) {
            System.out.println("You learn something new everyday :)");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(chemFact);
        }

        else if (science.contains("biology")) {
            bioFact = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Did you know The brain itself cannot feel pain? (yes or no)");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(bioFact);
        }

        if (bioFact.contains("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Well good for you");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(bioFact);
        } else if (bioFact.contains("no")) {
            System.out.println("You learn something new everyday :)");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(bioFact);
        }

        else if (science.contains("zoology")) {
            zooFact = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Did you know butterflies have taste receptors on their feet? (yes or no)");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(zooFact);
        }

        if (zooFact.contains("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Well good for you");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(zooFact);
        } else if (zooFact.contains("no")) {
            System.out.println("You learn something new everyday :)");
            inputContainsQuestionMark(zooFact);
        }
        inputContainsQuestionMark(input);

    }

private static void inputContainsQuestionMark(String science) {
    if (science.contains("?")) {
        System.out.println("I will be asking the questions");
    }
}
```

Comment: i gave it a shot and it just does the exact same thing as it is currently doing. Thanks for taking the time to reply tho :)